# Simple GUI with images

Tags: python, windows, image, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to display some cards on my simple GUI, but it's not showing up.

I've uploaded a working file with the .gif I want to upload, and the code is close but not right.
http://www.filedropper.com/cardgameproblem Size: 0Kb, Type:.zip

- Contains 1 .py and 1 .gif

The lines to look at start at 257-266. I know it's just a minor error, but I can't see it.

Please help

Comment: Please just post the code which is giving you problems, modified if necessary for us to understand it. I think few people (including me) are willing to download a zip and go through hundreds of lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tinkering, I found out that the image is properly displayed when stored in a variable of the GUI, i.e. using `self`

```
self.gif1 = PhotoImage(file='1.gif')
self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.gif1, anchor=NW)
```

<strike>I have no idea why, but</strike> This works, while naming the variable just `gif1` (or any other name), without `self`, does not. Tested both in your code and in a minimum example.

**Update:** As @Bryan pointed out, the garbage collector disposes the `PhotoImage` instance when `__init__` finishes. You have to keep a reference to the instance beyond the scope of the constructor, e.g. using `self`, or `global`. Given the problem at hand, it might be best to create a `dict`, storing the images using the names of the cards as keys.

Comment: The reason is that the python garbage collector will throw away the image when it detects there are no references to it. By saving it as an attribute of a class instance you prevent the garbage collector from throwing it away. Using a local variable like "gif1" causes it to be garbage collected when the function exits.

Comment: THANKYOU SO MUCH tobias_k. I 'accepted' your answer, but unfortunately I can't give rep yet (I'm new to the site.. <15). I can't tell you how much I appreciate it though