# Python Tkinter PhotoImage

Tags: python, class, tkinter

This is the format of code I currently have:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class mycustomwidow:
    def __init__(self,parent,......)
        ......
        ......
        tk.Label(parent,image=Myimage)
        tk.pack(side='top')

def main():
    root=tk.Tk()
    mycustomwindow(root)
    root.mainlopp()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My problem is: Where should I declare the photo `Myimage` that I used in my class `mycustomwindow`?

If I put `Myimage=tk.PhotoImage(data='....')` before the `root=tk.Tk()` like below, it will give me the `too early to create image` error as we can't create an image before the root window.

```
import Tkinter as tk
Myimage=tk.PhotoImage(data='....') 
class mycustomwidow:
    def __init__(self,parent,......)
        ......
        ......
        tk.Label(parent,image=Myimage)
        tk.pack(side='top')

def main():
    root=tk.Tk()
    mycustomwindow(root)
    root.mainlopp()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I put `Myimage=tk.PhotoImage(data='....')` in the function `main()` like this, it says it can't find the image `Myimage` in `class mycustomwindow`.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class mycustomwidow:
    def __init__(self,parent,......)
        ......
        ......
        tk.Label(parent,image=Myimage)
        tk.pack(side='top')

def main():
    root=tk.Tk()
    Myimage=tk.PhotoImage(data='....')
    mycustomwindow(root)
    root.mainlopp()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there anything badly wrong with my code structure? Where should I declare `Myimage` so that it can be used in `class mycustomwindow`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does not matter much where you declare the image, as long as

1. you create it *after* initializing `Tk()` (the problem in your first approach)
2. the image is *in the variable scope* when you are using it (the problem in your second approach)
3. the image object does *not get garbage-collected* (another [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067269/simple-gui-with-images/13068104#13068104) [pitfall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433771/python-tkinter-why-is-this-jpeg-not-showing/15435134#15435134))

If you define the image in your `main()` method, then you will have to make it `global`

```
class MyCustomWindow(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Tkinter.Label(self, image=image).pack()
        self.pack(side='top')

def main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    global image # make image known in global scope
    image = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file='image.gif')
    MyCustomWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Alternatively, you could drop your `main()` method entirely, making it global automatically:

```
class MyCustomWindow(Tkinter.Frame):
    # same as above

root = Tkinter.Tk()
image = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file='image.gif')
MyCustomWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Or, declare the image in your `__init__` method, but make sure to use the `self` keyword to bind it to your `Frame` object so it is not garbage collected when `__init__` finishes:

```
class MyCustomWindow(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.image = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file='image.gif')
        Tkinter.Label(self, image=self.image).pack()
        self.pack(side='top')

def main():
    # same as above, but without creating the image
```