# Use an image-button defined inside an object with TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to build a `tkinter` button with an image as background inside an object. It doesn't make any sense why the second implementation doesn't work !

Here are 3 very simple examples ; Who can explain the reason why the second implementation is not working?

(Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.)

### 1. Button created globally.

Works like a charm...

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from numpy import random
w = Tk()
def cb():
    print("Hello World")
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(random.random((50,50))))
b = Button(w, text="text", command=cb, image=image)
b.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

### 2. Button created inside the object `A` with a background image

The button doesn't work when clicked and doesn't display the image :(. There's clearly a problem but I don't understand it...

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from numpy import random
w = Tk()
class A():
    def __init__(self, w):
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(random.random((50,50))))
        b = Button(w, text="text", command=self.cb, image=image)
        b.pack()

    def cb(self):
        print("Hello World")

a = A(w)
w.mainloop()
```

### 3. Button created inside the object `A` without a background image

The button works properly, but I would like to display the image as well

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from numpy import random
w = Tk()
class A():
    def __init__(self, w):
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(random.random((50,50))))
        b = Button(w, text="text", command=self.cb)#, image=image)
        b.pack()

    def cb(self):
        print("Hello World")

a = A(w)
w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tricky indeed...and if you declare your `image` outside the class it works...maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760871/python-tkinter-photoimage) question could help...

Comment: However if you make it a class variable it works....

Comment: Simple answer is you need to add a special argument to the button that tells it to use both the image and text. `compound`. And change `image` to `self.image`.

Comment: @toti08 indeed… and actually, it's in the doc of `PhotoImage` 

Comment: @toti08 just to clarify you mean a class attribute. A variable is what they are using now. The class attribute is what we create with `self.`.

Comment: @Mike-SMT yes, true, sorry for the mess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood what happened. Thanks to the linked question what's happening in the second case is that your `image` gets garbage collected once the `__init__` method is finished. As a result your image is not available anymore to the root application, so it cannot be binded to it.
The way to solve it is to make it a class attribute:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, w):
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(random.random((50,50))))
        b = Button(w, text="text", command=self.cb, image=self.image)
        b.pack()

    def cb(self):
        print("Hello World")
```

Comment: This will correct the image issue but does not display text. So this is not quite a complete solution for the issue with the 2nd and 3rd block's of code.

Comment: @Mike-SMT in the original question the issue was with the image and the functioning of the button. I honestly didn't check the text displayed in the button...

Comment: Well the OP states *`The button works properly, but I would like to display the image as well`* so with that I would think the OP wants both the text and image to work. And considering they have both a text and image argument they likely want to use both.

Comment: That's because in example #3 he commented the `image=image` part out...at least I interpreted like this...

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems here.

The first problem is the image is not being saved after `__init__`. You probably know you need to save a reference to the image for it to be used in tkinter. You may not know that in a class if you do not assign the image to a class attribute it will not save the image after `__init__`.

So to fix the first issue you need change this:

```
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(random.random((50,50))))
```

To this:

```
# add self. to make it a class attribute and keep the reference alive for the image.
self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(random.random((50,50))))
```

The 2nd issue you may not notice here is that your text will not display while loading an image. This is because you need to add the argument `compound` in order for tkinter to display both an image and text in the button. That said you also need to update the image argument to include the new `self.image`.

So change this:

```
b = Button(w, text="text", command=self.cb, image=image)
```

To this:

```
# added compound and change text color so you can see it.
b = Button(w, compound="center" , text="text", fg="white", command=self.cb, image=self.image)
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thx. I realize my question was unclear about the "text". I don't need/want to make a text appear. I should have removed that option from the Button in the two first code snippets. Anyway, thanks for your answer which explains everything